# jQuery after replacing attribute value getting old value

Tags: jquery

I have span after img with attribute as clb-prodctid and its value is 280.

It is a close image & has background close image.

I am using function to replace `data-clb-prodctid="280"` to `data-clb-prodctid="281"`

Replace is working fine and it assigns new value properly.

But when I try to get the value, it gives me old value as 280.

After page refresh I get new value as 281.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img name="plus_icon" class="club_imgs imagefile club_imgs_1" data-clubprodnum="280" src="square.jpg">
    <span class="close_button close-btn-icon" onclick="removeproduct(this)" data-clb-prodctid="280">X</span>

    <script>
        function removeproduct(datas){                
            var remove_productId = jQuery(datas).data("clb-prodctid");

            alert(remove_productId);

            jQuery(".club_imgs_1").next('span').attr('data-clb-prodctid',281);                    
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are changing the `attr` on `.club_imgs_1` but it dont have an attribute called `data-clb-prodctid` Think you have to change `jQuery(".club_imgs_1")` to `jQuery(datas)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Data vs Attr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `data()` to read the data from jQuery's cache, but `attr()` to set the new value in the DOM only. Hence the new value is ignored.

To fix this use the setter of `data()`, like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.close_button').click(function() {
    var remove_productId = $(this).data("clb-prodctid");
    console.log(remove_productId);
    $(".club_imgs_1").next('span').data('clb-prodctid', 281);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img name="plus_icon" class="club_imgs imagefile club_imgs_1" data-clubprodnum="280" src="square.jpg">
<span class="close_button close-btn-icon" data-clb-prodctid="280">X</span>
```

Also note the preferred use of an unobtrusive event handler over an outdated `on*` event attribute in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `data` and not the `attr` :

```
 jQuery(".club_imgs_1").next('span').data('clb-prodctid',281);
```

Comment: Just FYI it should be `.data('clb-prodctid', 281);`

Answer (score 0):

and in addition it would be better if you use .on('click',()) rather than .click method, these two act different when you work with dynamic elements.

Comment: Your answer is not quite accurate. `on('click', fn)` and `click(fn)` are identical in behaviour. You're getting confused with the delegated event handler which is `$('parentSelector').on('click', 'childSelector', fn);`